# wget : Recursively search website for all files that end in file format?

Tags: python, wget

Is there a way to recursively search all sub-directories of a website for a specific file format?

http://somewebsite.com/parent/subdirectories/somefile.format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly simple just with `wget`:

```
wget -rA .format example.com
```

That will bumble around a domain looking and download any file that ends in `.format`.